# iPad app to live-sample vocals and repeat the sample in the background

Tags: software, voice

Hopefully someone here knows of any iPad app (any app is ok! I'll buy it!) that has a way that I can sing through a live microphone and then when I hold down a button (on a midi controller or the iPad screen) it will take a sample of the live mic input for as long as I hold the button and then echo (repeat gradually softer and softer) while I continue to sing.

So this is basically a quick way of layering vocals. I don't have any experience with loopers and such, but I'm asking this Q as a way to begin learning. Any relevant terminology would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

[Loopy](http://loopyapp.com/) is an excellent app which does this.

Loopy goes several steps further than a typical loop pedal.

- It allows for 6, 9 or 12 layered loops. They can be synchronised.
- You can create half, double, quadruple etc. length loops -- so for example, a one bar rhythm loop under a 12 bar melody loop.
- You can merge loops on the fly
- You can operate it using MIDI (e.g. a footswitch)
- etc.

Usually I say of software "this is not a recommendation". However, I *do* recommend Loopy.